# UiTableView to UiTableView to UiViewcontroller swift

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am new here and to coding and I need some help with a project that I'm currently stuck on.

I have built an app containing `UITableView` the first displays body areas (Gastro, cardio, respiratory, etc), the second displays more detailed features on the first (in gastro the table will display stomach, small intestine, colon, etc) and then the the `UIViewController` will have the more detailed info on the stomach etc.

I have this working all ok but one problem has arose. The `UIViewController`, regardless of which option is selected in the first table, displays the same info, i.e I get results for gastro even after selecting cardio etc.

Below is my code. I hope someone could help with this. I would really appreciate it!

```
import UIKit

class Chapters: UITableViewController {

    var ChaptersArray = [String]()

    var SubchaptersArray = [secondTable]()





    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



        // chapter names

        ChaptersArray = ["Gastrointestinal","Cardiovascular","Respiratory","Central Nervous System", "Infections"]


        // subcharpter names

        SubchaptersArray =  [secondTable(SecondTitle: ["Gas1", "Gas2", "Gas3", "Gas4"]),
                             secondTable(SecondTitle: ["Card1", "Card2", "Card3", "Card4"]),
                             secondTable(SecondTitle: ["Res1", "Res2", "Res3", "Res4"])]





    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func tableView(tableview: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as  UITableViewCell!


    cell.textLabel?.text = ChaptersArray[indexPath.row]




    return cell

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return ChaptersArray.count
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

        let destViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! Subchapters

        var secondTableArrayTwo : secondTable

        secondTableArrayTwo = SubchaptersArray[indexPath.row]

        destViewController.SubChaptersArray = secondTableArrayTwo.SecondTitle








    }



}







import UIKit

class Subchapters: UITableViewController {

    var SubChaptersArray = [String]()

    var identities = [String]()

    var data = [String]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        identities = ["G1","G2","G3","G4"]



    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return SubChaptersArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableview: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SecondCell") as  UITableViewCell!

        cell.textLabel?.text = SubChaptersArray[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    // ignore
    // override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    //  let destViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DrugNotes

    // destViewController.FirstString = "drug data: need to seperate out to seperate pages" }




    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let vcName = identities[indexPath.row]

        let viewcontroller = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(vcName)

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewcontroller!, animated: true)





    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: How do you tell the `UIViewController` what was selected from the second table?

Comment: I think that is my issue and where I am goin wrong. But unsure how best to fix the problem

Comment: You say it displays results for gastro.  How is it choosing that category now?

Comment: Ah sorry, using the string identites and then have g1, g2, etc as the corresponding UiViewControllers. It's contained in the code for the subchapters

Comment: Anyone have any ideas of how to resolve this?

Comment: @PhillipMills Any suggestions? Would love to be able to sort this problem out as its really setting me back. Thanks